# Inheriting model in rails engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I have a main app and an admin engine in Rails 4. I would like to extend some functionality of the main user model that will be only available for admins. My project folder looks like this:

```
app
--models
----user.rb
----profile.rb
admin
--app
----models
------admin
--------user.rb
```

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :profile
end
```

admin/app/models/admin/user.rb

```
module Admin
    class User < ::User
        def to_s
             "#{member_number} #{profile.first_name} #{profile.last_name}"
        end
    end
end
```

When the engine is mounted it doesn't use its user model. It only loads the main user model.
What is the best way to inherit/extend an App model in the Rails Engines?